# Superset exporting and importing the Dashboards using CLI (for versioning control)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, apache-superset

Goal: My goal is to export the all the dashboards from the superset so that I can save them as backup and also make sure that I can import them.

Existing setup: I am cloning [superset from git](https://github.com/apache/superset.git) and using `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`
to setup and run the superset (following this [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose))

Issue:
Using superset CLI: I am using [this documentation](https://support.websoft9.com/docs/superset/solution-cli.html)
to connect to the existing docker image on which superset is running and then running `superset export-dashboards` but it throws the following error:

---

```
    Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py]
logging was configured successfully
2021-10-20 06:54:49,727:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2021-10-20 06:54:49,732:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:201: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn(
Starting export
2021-10-20 06:54:50,962:INFO:superset.utils.dashboard_import_export:Starting export
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/superset/cli.py", line 413, in export_dashboards
    data = dashboard_import_export.export_dashboards(db.session)
  File "/app/superset/utils/dashboard_import_export.py", line 33, in export_dashboards
    data = Dashboard.export_dashboards(dashboard_ids)
  File "/app/superset/models/dashboard.py", line 385, in export_dashboards
    json_metadata = json.loads(dashboard.json_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

---

Kindly help me debug, I have also changed the "VERSIONED_EXPORT": True

Comment: interesting, i see the same

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed Apache Superset with Docker, this is how to successfully export dashboards.

**Prerequisite**: I assume you correctly deployed Superset. Here is a quick example

```bash
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
cd superset
git checkout 3.0.0
TAG=3.0.0 docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

In case you did not modify the deployment, your running services should look like this:

```bash
docker compose ps
```

```bash
NAME                   IMAGE                                                  SERVICE
superset_app           apachesuperset.docker.scarf.sh/apache/superset:3.0.0   superset
superset_cache         redis:7                                                redis
superset_db            postgres:14                                            db
superset_worker        apachesuperset.docker.scarf.sh/apache/superset:3.0.0   superset-worker
superset_worker_beat   apachesuperset.docker.scarf.sh/apache/superset:3.0.0   superset-worker-beat
```

The service name for `superset_app` container is `superset`.

#### Export

Create the export zip:

```bash
docker compose exec superset superset export-dashboards
```

Look for the export zip's filename `dashboard_export_20230922T132800.zip`:

```bash
docker compose exec superset ls -l
```

```bash
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     238373 Sep 22 13:28 dashboard_export_20230922T132800.zip
```

Copy the export zip from the container to your host:

```bash
docker compose cp superset:/app/dashboard_export_20230922T132800.zip .
```

[Link to the docs](https://superset.apache.org/docs/miscellaneous/importing-exporting-datasources)